# WSO2 Identity Server claims no longer mapping 6.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

This was working correctly in version 5.11.0. In my configuration I had a service provider setup to authenticate inbound requests using OAuth2 which was connected to a federated identity provider. The federated identity provider would authenticate using SAML2. When the SAML2 request is sent back the assertion would be sent to the /oauth2/token using the "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer" grant type. The SAML2 assertion would contain a list of user attributes that would map to oidc claims. Now, in version 6.1.0, using the same process no longer works and the claims do not get mapped. I checked to make sure the mappings were setup as they were in 5.11.0.

Comment: can i know what are the claims not getting mapped ? FYI: from IS 6 user ID is used as the default subject identifier instead of username: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12504

Comment: @Asha The userid is the only claim that is getting mapped correctly. All other claims do not map. For instance, I have a claim called "givenname" and it doesn't get mapped. I'm using the correct scope of "profile" per the documentation. I have about 7 other claims that are coming over in the saml assertion and they don't get mapped.

Comment: If possible can you add a screenshot of the OIDC scope config (scope and list of claims that comes under the 'profile' scope) and SP claim configuration?

Comment: Can you check the claims you wanted are configured in profile scope and configured under the SP as well ? Also the SP claims are marked as mandatory claim?

Comment: @Asha I managed to fix the issue. It seemed not having the identity provider setup to provision the users was the problem. I didn't have to do this on version 5.11.0 and would prefer not to provision the users.

Comment: Glad to know that you've solved the issue :)